# Why is my answer in the compiler not the same, with the answer from leetcode compiler?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple code, its essence is to remove duplicate numbers from a sheet. But on my server, the data received does not match the data on leetcode. For what reason could this be?

```java
var deleteDuplicates = (head) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < head.length; i++) {
        for(let a = i + 1; a < head.length; a++) {
            if(head[i] === head[a] ) {
                head.splice([a], 1)
            } 
        }
    } 
    return head;
};
console.log(deleteDuplicates([1,1,2]));
```

Output: [1,2]

Leetcode:
Your input
[1,1,2]
Output
[1,1,2]
Expected
[1,2]

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-list/

Comment: Modifying lists that you are iterating over is not advisable.

Comment: The function name is wrong. It should be `removeDuplicates`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a `Set`? It's simpler and you'll avoid modifying a list that you're iterating over.

```
var deleteDuplicates = (head) => [...new Set(head)];
```

Comment: What's wrong with the given code? The output seems to be correct.

Comment: How does the new Set method work in this function? How did you do filtering with 1 method?

Comment: From docs: "The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references. Set objects are collections of values. You can iterate through the elements of a set in insertion order. A value in the Set may only occur once; it is unique in the Set's collection." If you want to find more on how Sets work you can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set